# Inverse Laplace transform is not giving the same result with 2 different theorems

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I'm trying to transform this image function back to its original :

$$ F(s) = \frac{5}{s^2 -4s-32} (I)$$

I tried first to use **the convolution theorem** :
$\mathcal{F}(f*g)=\mathcal{F}(f)\mathcal{F}(g)$

$=> 5 . \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{5}{s^2 -4s-32}) = 5\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{1}{(s-8)(s+4)}) = 5 e^{4t} (*)
$(Inverse Laplace transform)

With the ***partial fraction decomposition*** I got a different result :

$\frac{A}{s-8} + \frac{B}{s-4}   => A = 5/12 $   and  $ B=-5/12 $ which will lead to a different result
$ F(s) = \frac{5}{12(s-8)} -\frac{5}{12(s+4)}  $
=> $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$(II)$ $= $ \frac{5}{12}(e^{8t} - e^{-4t} ) (**)$(Inverse Laplace transform)

What am I doing wrong here ? Why are $(*)$ and $(**)$ not having the same result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistakenly write that f*g is just (f times g), when instead you meant to use $f*g = \int_0^t f(z)g(t-z) dz$.

Comment: Oh I see thanks